# Keep Task and Task.FromResult if method is synchronous or remove Task-stuff at all?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have a Web API controller (ASP.NET Core 5). Some of my APIs are asynchronous and some of them not. My question is next: Is there any advantages of using `public **Task<T>** WebApiMethod + Task.FromResult()` in Web API controllers if my method is synchronous?

For example:

```
public Task<string> GetSomeData()
{
    // some synchronous processing...
    return Task.FromResult(result);
}
```

Should I turn the example code above to something like this?

```
public string GetSomeData()
{
    // some synchronous processing...
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the api is doing synchronous work it should have a synchronous signature. it will make the readability and understanding of the function clearer to other developers and will prevent misunderstanding when reading this function again in the future.

In the future, if the method will need to be modified to have an asynchronous task to do, you can change the signature to have an asynchronous signature.

Comment: I just hoped that methods with ```Task``` signatures would give some advantages in Web API. :)

Comment: @TiberSeptim it gives a *dis*advantage. An extra `Task` object is allocated and the runtime code has to generate a state machine to await it. These objects need to be garbage-collected. Over time, this adds up to a lot of wasted RAM, CPU and latency, especially for busy web APIs.

Answer (score 1):

You should use synchronous methods if the work is synchronous.

Yet, you should use `Task` signatures if you use some form of caching (e.g. with the proxy pattern). Then, of course if you already did the expensive I/O work, use `Task.FromResult` to return the cached result, and return the I/O task if it has to be newly downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't have much difference in the way it is executed. If you can make the processing part asynchronous then it would make some difference.

Comment: It *does* make a difference. An extra task is allocated to wrap the result. ASP.NET has to await that task to get its value which means it has to use `await` and generate a state machine for that call. These things add up in a web application and eliminating them is one of the reasons ASP.NET Core is so much faster than ASP.NET Old. What's probably worse though is lying to callers about the method's behavior - when you see `Task` you assume the method is truly asynchronous and write your code accordingly